# Add name in correct alphabetical position in a python list

Tags: python

I need to add the user's input in the right order on the list named 'vetor'. I tried using a backup but I stoped there, because when I printed the backup it was not even complete. Thanks for all of your time!

Here's my code:

```html
vetor = ["alvaro", "beto", "carlos", "rodrigo"]
back = []
nome = input("Digite o nome: ")
for x in range(len(vetor)):
    if vetor[x] == nome[0:len(vetor[x])] and len(vetor[x]) < len(nome):
        back.append(vetor[x])
        back.append(nome)
    if vetor[x][0:len(nome)] == nome and len(vetor[x]) > len(nome):
        back.append(nome)
        back.append(vetor[x])
    if ord(vetor[x][0]) < ord(nome[0]):
        back.append(vetor[x])
    elif len(vetor[x]) < len(nome):
        for n in range(len(vetor[x])):
            if ord(nome[n]) == ord(vetor[x][n]) and ord(nome[n+1]) < ord(vetor[x][n+1]):
                    back.append(nome)
                    back.append(vetor[x])
            elif ord(nome[n+1]) > ord(vetor[x][n+1]):
                back.append(vetor[x])
    elif len(vetor[x]) > len(nome):
        for n in range(len(nome)):
            if ord(nome[n]) == ord(vetor[x][n]) and ord(nome[n+1]) < ord(vetor[x][n+1]):
                back.append(nome)
                back.append(vetor[x])
            elif ord(nome[n]) == ord(vetor[x][n]) and ord(nome[n+1]) > ord(vetor[x][n+1]):
                back.append(vetor[x])
```

print(back)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have enough names in your list so that

```
vetor = sorted(vetor + [nome])
```

is out of the question? If not, use it. You can always optimize when you realize that it's too slow.

Otherwise, if you like, there's the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) which provides a method for inserting stuff into sorted lists:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> vetor = ["alvaro", "beto", "carlos", "rodrigo"]
>>> bisect.insort(vetor, "bob")
>>> vetor
['alvaro', 'beto', 'bob', 'carlos', 'rodrigo']
>>> bisect.insort(vetor, "dave")
>>> vetor
['alvaro', 'beto', 'bob', 'carlos', 'dave', 'rodrigo']
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have to implement your own sort routine, use `sorted(iterable)` instead like this:

```
vetor = ["alvaro", "beto", "carlos", "rodrigo"]
print sorted(vetor) # Returns a new sorted list

nome = input("Digite o nome: ") # Ok, if you are using python3, use raw_input if you are using python2.

vetor.append(nome)
print sorted(vetor) # Returns a new sorted list with the new item appended.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your list is already sorted. You can use [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to insert it in the right spot. One option is to use bisect.insort_left as I show below. You can check the module for other options.

```
>>> import bisect
>>> vetor = ["alvaro", "beto", "carlos", "rodrigo"]
>>> bisect.insort_left(vetor, "new name")
>>> vetor
['alvaro', 'beto', 'carlos', 'new name', 'rodrigo']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
vetor = ["alvaro", "beto", "carlos", "rodrigo"]
nome = raw_input("Digite o nome: ")  # for python 2
n = len(vetor)
i = 0
while i < n:
  if nome < vetor[i]: break
  i = i+1
vetor = vetor[0:i] + [nome] + vetor[i:]
print vetor
```